# Label in UICollectionReusableView always nil

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

As the title states, I have a label in a UICollectionReusableView. The view I use is dequeued successfully using the following:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        let hourCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(kind, withReuseIdentifier:"Hour", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! HourCollectionReuseableView;
        let time = String(indexPath.item) + "H";
        hourCell.setTime(time);
        return hourCell;
    }
```

Here is the Interface builder view of `HourCollectionReuseableView`. I note here that I do this in the custom class of file owner:

[image]

Here is the Collection Reuse Identifier:

[image]

Here is the `HourCollectionReuseableView` class:

```
class HourCollectionReuseableView: UICollectionReusableView {

    @IBOutlet weak var hourLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var hourDividerLine: UIView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib();
    }

    func setTime(time:String) {
        self.hourLabel.text = time;
    }
```

In my view controller I register the class as follows:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad();
        self.collectionView.registerClass(HourCollectionReuseableView.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: "Hour", withReuseIdentifier:"Hour");
    }
```

The code keeps crashing on `self.hourLabel.text = time` with the following error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: in here you get the output  let time = String(indexPath.item) + "H"; or not

Comment: Check your `hourLabel` is connected with view?

Comment: You don't need to register your cell while using storyboard. Also check you are not assigning any `nil` value to Label. crash is because of null value assignment.

Comment: You can try using registerNib instead of registerClass. e.g. self.collectionView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "HourCollectionReuseableView", bundle: nil), forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "Hour")

Comment: remove register class from viewdidload

Answer (score 10):

Just as @firstinq pointed out, as you're working with a `.xib` in your `HourCollectionReuseableView`, you should try using `registerNib` instead of `registerClass`.

So, you're code should look more like

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad();
    self.collectionView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "HourCollectionReuseableView", bundle: nil), forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "Hour");
}
```